# ConcurrentModificationException-ArrayList

Tags: android, exception, bitmap

I have been through the documentation and multiple related posts, but am unable to detect where and why the exception is occurring in my code. I'm trying to click an image, display it in a recyclerview (for which I'm storing the path in an ArrayList) and upload them. I have two ArrayLists- one for the smaller bitmaps to display in recyclerView and one for the larger bitmaps to upload.

This is the code to capture the image:

```
           public void captureImage(){
    camera.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) {
            super.onPictureTaken(picture);
            upload_bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);
            large_bitmap=getResizedBitmap(upload_bitmap,500);
            result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);
            bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, bytes);
            Bitmap newResult=getResizedBitmap(result,400,400);
            String fileNameSmall = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.txt'").format(new Date());
            String fileNameLarge= new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss'.txt'").format(new Date());
            path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), newResult, fileNameSmall, null);
            large_bitmap_path= MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), large_bitmap, fileNameLarge, null);
            c = Calendar.getInstance();
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            tf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss  a");
            formattedTime=tf.format(c.getTime());
            formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            fileName="999999_".concat(formattedDate.toString()).concat(" at ").concat(formattedTime.toString()).concat(".jpg");
            String uploadName=fileName;
            Log.e("fileName",uploadName);
            fileNameList.add(fileName);
            horizontalList.add(path);
            large_bitmapList.add(Uri.parse(large_bitmap_path));
            i++;
            iterator = horizontalList.iterator();
            recycleViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    camera.captureImage();

}
```

And this is the code to upload the image:

```
      final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         String img_path=image_path;
            //Converting Bitmap to String

            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> parameters = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            //Adding parameters
            parameters.put("dateTime", "2017-10-09 01.43 PM");
            parameters.put("type", "image");
            parameters.put("fileName",fileNameList.get(j));
            j++;
            //returning parameters
            return parameters;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Apparently I'm not sure where the exception occurs. The works sometimes but sometimes,  it crashes as soon as I open the camera. 
Also, storing two images of different sizes in not a good idea, any suggestions are welcome. 
Please try to help instead of downvoting. Thanks.

The Logcat

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>                                                                                            at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:346)
>                                                                                            at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:366)
>                                                                                            at android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.flatten(Camera.java:4243)
>                                                                                            at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:3215)
>                                                                                            at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.setFlash(Camera1.java:139)
>                                                                                            at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.adjustCameraParameters(Camera1.java:376)
>                                                                                            at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.openCamera(Camera1.java:317)
>                                                                                            at com.flurgle.camerakit.Camera1.start(Camera1.java:85)
>                                                                                            at com.flurgle.camerakit.CameraView$3.run(CameraView.java:216)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

PS Camerakit is a library I used to create a custom adapter

Comment: can you post the error logs as well

Comment: Yes. Give me a minute

Comment: looks as your operations are not thread safe. Are you calling a method from different threads? Also the `captureImage` method, where exactly are you calling it. Also your code is not memory friendly. you're creating too many bitmaps. One better way to do this is to create a new activity and add a fab which opens it. Capture an image from the new activity and then push just the URI of the image to the recyclerview.

Comment: I'm calling a method from a different method. The captureImage is called on button.OnClickListener.I know the code is not memory friendly. I'll work on it as soon as I'm done with the exception.

Comment: where is the `onClickListener` method written? inside the recyclerview adapter?

Comment: Wait, I'll update the code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156520/discussion-between-madscientist-and-harshita).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that's happening here is that you're trying to set a new `cameraListener` on every `onClick` event of your button.

`CameraKit` library has a function, `camera.captureImage()` use this method inside your `onClick` implementation. M

Move the `cameraListener` out of the `onClick` implementation.

The exception clearly states that you're trying to modify a value concurrently. Possibly because you're adding a new listener everytime.

So you final code should be something like this:

#### 1. Your onclick:

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) { 
try{ 
camera.captureImage();  
} 
catch (Exception exception){ 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please wait",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 

} 
});
```

#### 2. Your listener:

```
camera.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() { 
@Override 
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) { 
super.onPictureTaken(picture); 
upload_bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length); 
result = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length); 
captureImage(); 
} 
});
```

#### 3. Your captureImage(Bitmap bitmap):

Save the bitmap and return a uri